# Angular Is it an anti-pattern to use a service method in a template

Tags: angular

I was wondering if using a service method in a template was an anti-pattern in Angular6 :

By instance

**component.ts**

```
constructor(public myService: MyService) {}
```

**component.html**

```
<div>{{myService.getItems() | async}}</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is. You should be assigning the observable returned from the method to a property in your component and then use it in your template.

```
myObservable$;

constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.myObservable$ = this.myService.getItems();
}
```

And in your template:

```
<div>{{myObservable$ | async}}</div>
```

### REASON(S)

There are several reasons for doing this.

1. This implementation has a **better separation of concerns**. It hides the implementation logic from the template. The template should only need to know about the Observable. It doesn't need to know things like where exactly did the Component get this value from. Which Service's which method did it call to get this observable?
2. It promotes a pattern that can be **better Unit Tested**. You won't be able to do this if you're calling the service's method in your template.

Comment: What's the reason behind it, it seems to add quite a lot of boiler plate ?

Comment: https://blog.appverse.io/why-it-is-a-bad-idea-to-use-methods-in-the-html-templates-with-angular-2-30d49f0d3b16

Answer (score 2):

In most cases it's probably a bad idea due to reasons that were already provided in the comments, e.g. this [link](https://blog.appverse.io/why-it-is-a-bad-idea-to-use-methods-in-the-html-templates-with-angular-2-30d49f0d3b16) Sachila posted or Siddharth mentioned in his answer.

Nevertheless, even in the [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#bind-to-the-messageservice) they do access the service directly, however it seems to be just accessing a property not a method and especially not a method that performs expensive operations.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not

According to the official documentation, injecting public service to bind it in the template is not an anti-pattern.
https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt4#bind-to-the-messageservice